# Rotativa BuildPdf is working on local computer but not on production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, rotativa

I am using Rotativa to generate a pdf from a view I have created. Locally this works fine, the pdf is stored on my local computer and the email functiont then attaches and sends the file. But when I release it on our server, it basically breaks at this part:

```
var binary = pdf.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);
```

The website takes ages to load and then finally just says

> Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

What i did to test this was to redirect to the actual view which will be generated in a pdf until this error was shown. I thought the issue was that the website does not have any write rights but could create directories in the required folder up until the above part mentioned.

What can I do to solve this?

Here is my full section of code for this part:

```
string Switches = string.Format("--print-media-type --header-html {0} --footer-html {1}", Url.Action("Header", "Home", new { area = "" }, "http"), Url.Action("Footer", "Home", new { area = "" }, "http"));

                var fileName = ReportName+objScor.Name+"_"+objScor.Surname + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HHmmss") + ".pdf";

                var filePath =(@"C:\\PDFReport\\" + fileName);

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\\PDFReport\\"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\\PDFReport\\");
                }




                var pdf = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("Report", report)
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                    CustomSwitches = Switches

                };
                var binary = pdf.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found that if I remove the "Switches" part and comment out `CustomSwitches = Switches `, The pdf is created on the server and also sends out. This is fine, but now I don't have any images displaying on the pdf. Even if I add an image on the view, it does not return it from the server side and a bland report does not do the application justice. So if anyone has any solution to this, it would be much appreciated.